# How to call jQuery properly from an AngularJS controller

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs

I'm trying to use jQuery-UI tabs with AngularJS.

See the example [here](http://plunker.no.de/edit/pNvygT?live=preview)

Problem is that calling `jQuery("#tabs").tabs();` in the controller seems to hook up "half" of what's needed to "tabbify" something.

Ideas?

Answer (score 14):

You should not be doing DOM manipulation in your controller - at all. Rather, you should use directives.

I have been developing a set of directives for my own use: https://github.com/ganarajpr/Angular-UI-Components

The philosophy is to just drop this simple pieces of code in the directives file:

```
.directive('maketab',function() {
        return function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            elm.tabs({
                show: function(event, ui) {
                        scope.$broadcast("tabChanged",ui);
                }
            });
        };
    })
```

Then, in the div which you would like to convert into a tab:

```
<div id="mytab" maketab>

<ul>
....
</ul>

<div>...</div>
...
</div>
```

*Note that the div and its child structures should conform to what JQuery UI asks it to be.*

For a more robust example and more components, check out the github repo.

Comment: I have been experiencing the same trouble, even applying the directive stuff (as you can see [here](http://plunker.no.de/edit/SzvzCB?live=preview))

Comment: hey @ganaraj, can you bind click handlers programmatically? I'm building an app to graphically build table relationships (from json). So let's say I want to add a new table on the canvas when I right click. how could I go about this? I'm very new to angular but not to Js or Jquery.

Comment: @berto77 You can. I would suggest you to take care of all that inside of a directive though because that seems to be the most logical place to do it. I have been thinking of a way of making angular and canvas work together. I am not sure if they are suitable for each other because they target different use cases...While angular is for web apps, canvas would suit well for games (which I think is a different scenario )

Comment: @ganaraj I disagree.  I am currently building a WebGL browser strategy game.  Currently I have a canvas with a jquery ui overlay.  I am very excited about using angular for my ui components, but the canvas is still a core element for drawing the universe.

Comment: @mattblang what do you disagree with? If you are putting a directive on a canvas and handling everything inside of that directive that pretty much annuls all the power that angular gives, isnt it? 
Manipulating the pixels in a canvas seem very "DOM manipulation"y ..So it doesnt seem to naturally fit inside of a controller ..